# Candidate changes in 2024 Moderator Election – review your ballot

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

### TL;DR: There's been a change in the candidate list for the 2024 Moderator Election. The voting period has been extended for a week. If you've already voted, you should confirm your votes still accurately represent your preferences.

After the election concluded its nomination phase and moved on to voting, it came to our attention that one of the nominees' nomination statements contained substantial portions of AI-generated content. Given that [Code Review's policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy) completely disallows any such content, we have withdrawn that nomination from this election.

This decision was not made lightly. The title and responsibilities of a moderator come with a heavy burden. As [the election page states](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/4), they “are [accorded the highest level of privilege on our community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/?_ga=2.34688169.962481472.1648163048-1033621334.1635450510), and should themselves be exemplars of positive behavior and leaders within the community.”

We understand that by making this decision it will cause some stress during the voting phase of the election. This is the sort of thing we ideally like to catch before an election moves into voting. However, our utmost responsibility as Community Managers is to the community as a whole, and by extension, the integrity of the election process. We believe it would be remiss to not intervene. Our network is run by a standard of rules that apply to all users which means that even nominees are not exempt.

Given the short notice between this action and the conclusion of the voting period, we're also extending the voting period for one more week. The new conclusion date for voting is now April 3, 2024, at 20:00UTC.

Please check that your votes still reflect your preferences given the changes to the candidate list.